# Store items with same keys and different values in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need a state variable to be defined in a constructor to store below items:

1. abc = 123
2. abc = 456
3. abc = 349
4. def = 378
5. def = 348
6. xyz = 123
7. xyz = 234

Also, I need following functions on the variable:

1. insert new item. examples: with abc = 234, xyz = 239
2. Delete abc with value 123.
3. search if item already exists before inserting/deleting:
   if (abc with value 123) is present in the variable.

What are different ways to do that? And what is the best way out of it?

As of now, I am doing something like this

```
//selectedCars= {} is a dictionary defined in the state contructor of other class

class xyz extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

getMeSomething(car, color, event){
//car can be any car like honda or mercedes
//selected cars is a dictionary that is passed from other class in to this class as props
        var existingValues = []
        if (this.props.selectedCars[car] != undefined) {
            existingValues = this.props.selectedCars[car];
        }
        var indexOfCar = existingValues.indexOf(car);
        if (indexOfCar == -1) {
            if (event.target.checked) {
                existingValues.push(car);
            }
        }
        else if (!event.target.checked) {                 
                existingValues.splice(indexOfCar, 1);
        }
        this.props.selectedCars[car] = existingValues
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ ...}}>
                {
                this.props.cars.map((car, i) => {
                    return <div key={i}><span className="yhn"><label><input type="checkbox" onChange={this.getMeSomething.bind(this, car, this.props.color)} /><span></span></label>{car}</span></div>
                    })
                }
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Please share your attempted code.

Comment: @HassanImam I tried dictionary something like this filteredColumns: {}. But, then realized it as not a great solution.

Comment: I am guessing those are objects and you would want store them in an array?  You can't store them directly on the state object with duplicate property names.

Comment: You can use Object or Map for this.

Comment: @WilliamFleming I have updated above with what I have as of now in my code. So, was finding if there are some other ways to do this as I am bit new to the UI stuff and also if this would yield good performance result.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Array model.
You can easily find the stored item on it if exists.

Look:

```
abc=[];
abc [0]=123;
abc [1]=456;
//and it is better to add them like below:
abc.push (789);
abc.push (101);
```

And to find out if your variable stored on abc before you have to use index of function :

```
I = abc.indexOf(456); // Returns 1 that means you can find 456 on abc [1]
I2 = abc.indexOf (999); // Returns -1 that means the 999 is not stored on abc yet
```

And the performance is perfect and you don't need to worry about your search.

However, based on your usage, Objects or dictionaries can be useful to. So let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have updated above with what I have as of now in my code. So, was finding if there are some other ways to do this as I am bit new to the UI stuff and also if this would yield good performance result. For array operations, it is more or less what you said. But, what I wanted was something like a storage where there can be same keys with different values.